# Can't run my test from only one class using testNG, maven, NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, testng

I created maven java project with 
[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJbQF.png)
Then, created two TestNG cases called 'Test1.java' and 'Test2.java' in 'test' package. Also added 'NewTestNGSuite.xml'
['NewTestNGSuite.xml'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S14x.png)
Test1.java contains:

```
package tests;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test1 {

    public Test1() {
    }
    @Test
     public void test_01() {
         System.out.println("\nFIRST!");
     }
     @Test
     public void test_02() {
         System.out.println("\nSECOND!");
     }
}
```

Test2.java contains:

```
    package tests;

    import static org.testng.Assert.*;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class Test2 {

        public Test2() {
        }
        @Test
         public void test_03() {
             System.out.println("\nTHIRD!");
         }
         @Test
         public void test_04() {
             System.out.println("\nFOURTH!");
         }
    }
```

NewTestNGSuite.xml contains:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="tests" verbose="1">
   <test name="Test1" parallel="false">
        <classes>
                <class name="tests.Test1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When I right click on NewTestNGSuite.xml and then 'Test File' it runs all my tests from Test1.java and from Test2.java

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AcHR.png)

What should I do to run tests only from Test1.java using NewTestNGSuite.xml?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>testNG</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                   <version>6.8</version>
                   <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
      </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: please add (relevant) code from your POM here instead of providing a screenshot.

Comment: @Michael, Code was added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the wanted xml file to the pom.xml under surefire plugin:

```
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
     <suiteXmlFile>NewTestNGSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Or just add surefire plugin and choose your xml file with maven command:

```
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=NewTestNGSuite.xml test
```

I guess you can customize each maven command from NetBeans too.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it has to execute only Test1 class, as according to  defined class.

Can you please update Testng dependency version to 6.14.3 I have seen you are using older version.

Make sure to maven clean and Test it.

Answer (score 0):

try to retain only this in your XML and try again.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="tests">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.Test1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

verbose and parallel deceleration are not mandatory.